# Como reenviar request que falló por error "csrf token distmacth" una vez que ya se recupero

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

estoy trabajando con vue y laravel y cree un interceptor para caprturar mis errores,

```
window.axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
   return response;
}, 
error => {

    const {
        config,
        response: {status, data}
} = error;


const originalRequest = config;

store.commit('returnCodeInterceptor', {
    'status': error.response.status,
    'data': error.response.data,
    'originalRequest': error.response.config,
    'error': error
})
console.log('interceptor 1 data', error.response.config)
console.log('interceptor 2', error.response.status)
console.log('interceptor 3', error.response.data)


if (error.response) throw 108;
// este trow evita que se cierre el modal de los formularios
```

})

funciona bien hasta ahi.. cuando recibo un error 419 de que se perdio el token, lo que hago es llamarle a un metodo en laravel que me devuelve el nuevo token y lo actualizo asi

```
async refreshToken(state, parametro) {

            if (state.refrescando == 3) return null;
            if (parametro.data.message != "CSRF token mismatch.") return null;

            try {

                const response = await axios.get('/admin/home/refreshToken');
                window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
                window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = response.data;
                console.log('refreshToken', response)
                this.commit('originalRequest', parametro)
                state.refrescando = state.refrescando + 1
                
            } catch(error) {
                console.log('el error es', error)
                // me.commit("notifyInfo", "Error de autenticacion (419).. La pagina se recargará automaticamente");
                // setTimeout( function() {
                //     // location.assign('/admin/home');
                // }, 5000);
            }
        },
```

hasta aca todo funciona muy bien.. el problema es que yo no quiero que el usuario vuelva hacer click en un button para reenviar la solicitud... entonces estroy tratando de volver a enviar la solicitud por debajo

```
originalRequest(state, data) {
        axios.request(data.originalRequest).then(response => {
            console.log('originalRequest Response', response)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('volvio a reventar', error)
        });
    },
```

Aquí es donde esta el problema, por alguna razón esto me vuelve a arrojar un error 419 de  "csrf token distmacth"  a pesar de que ya actualice mi axios y lo que hace es entrar en un bucle infinito.. alguna idea de porque pasa esto?

Comment: Me parece que estás confundido... ¿haces una llamada axios para obtener el token crsf? ¿por qué no lo pones en una etiqueta y lo tomas de ahí?

Comment: eso esta en una etiqueta, el chiste es recuperar el token cuando expira sin recargar la pagina